# .NET Application to Capture Image from PDA Camera

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to capture images from a PDA camera by clicking the 
capture button in my application so that I can save (using 
save button in my application) it in my application (I also 
need to zoom the picture through my application by clicking 
the zoom Button.)

I have to do this in .NET using C#.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: What connexion do you use ? bluetooth, wifi, cable... ?

Comment: Do you mean zoom on the taken picture or using the zoom of the camera.

Comment: is your application for PDA itself?

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0 of the .NET Compact Framework provides the [CameraCaptureDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.forms.cameracapturedialog.showdialog.aspx) to add camera support to your application. Unfortunately, it's limited to activating the camera and waiting for the user to take a picture or cancel the dialog. You would need to perform the zoom on the still image after it has been captured.

Alternatively, there are some 3rd party components available for accessing the the camera. One such component is [showcased on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/MobileAppDeveloperPack.aspx), but you will obviously need to license the components for your app.